# What's an ADL with three variables called? (ADL(p,q) vs ADL(p,q,g) vs ?)

Tags: time-series, cointegration, notation, ardl

In every example I've seen, there are just two variables in an ADL(p,q) (in relation to cointegration) where p and q are the numbers of lags included for each variable.

What is the correct/standard notation for an **Autoregressive Distributed Lag model (ADL)** with three variables:

$x_{1_t} =a* x_{1_t-1}+ b * x_{2_t} + c*x_{3_t}  + .. + \epsilon_t$ ?

ADL(p,q,g) or similar?